# How can I sort a list of files by the multiple components in their names?

Tags: perl

I have list of Arrays (INPUT) listed below: Required output in the second column.

Hint: Sequence order must be based on the Colur MODE (wc, gs, pc).

```
        INPUT                           OUTPUT
        -----                           ------
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio1.tif     PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio2.tif     PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio3.tif     PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio4.tif     PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio1.tif     PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio2.tif     PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio3.tif     PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f4.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio4.tif     PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f4.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f1.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f5.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f1.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f5.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f2.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f6.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f2.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f7.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f3.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f8.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f3.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f9.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f4.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f9.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f4.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f10.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f5.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f10.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f5.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f11.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f6.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f7.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f12-1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f8.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f9.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f12-2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f9.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-11.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f10.tif      PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f12-11.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f10.tif      PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f11.tif      PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f12-11.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f12-1.tif        PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f12-2.tif        PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-1.tif        PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-11.tif       PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio4.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-2.tif        PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio4.tif
```

Code:

Bit of code:

```
#-------------------->
sub IMGSValidations
#-------------------->
{
    my @ChkAllImgs = @_; my @backImgs = @ChkAllImgs; my $figname = join "\n", @ChkAllImgs;
    my @sorted_array = ();
    $WC_TrFl = $GS_TrFl = $PC_TrFl = 'False';

    my $ImgFileJoinTemp = join "\n", @backImgs;

    if($ImgFileJoinTemp=~m/\_f(\d+)\-/)
    {
        @sorted_array = sort {
          my ($anum) = ($a =~ /\-(\d+)\./);
          my ($bnum) = ($b =~ /\-(\d+)\./);
          $anum <=> $bnum
        } @backImgs;
    }
    if($ImgFileJoinTemp=~m/\_f(\d+)/)
    {
        @sorted_array = sort {
          my ($anum) = ($a =~ /\_f(\d+)/);
          my ($bnum) = ($b =~ /\_f(\d+)/);
          $anum <=> $bnum
        } @backImgs;
    }

    $figname = join "\n", @sorted_array;
    my $FigListText = "$curDir/Test.txt"; writeFileinString($FigListText,\$figname);
}
```

I am not getting the expected output. Could someone please advice to get the output.

Comment: You didn't specify the sort order... The ones with `f` appear to be sorted by the two `f` # numbers then by the colour mode. But why is `bio` after after `f`?

Comment: Also, one of your sort criteria appears to be gs → wc → pc, but there are two exceptions to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining the sort order is the first thing you need to do. If you can't describe the sort order to a person, you can't possibly describe it to Perl.

To do that, we'll need some nomenclature. The names of the *www* have these parts:

- The *xxx* (`PDIS`)
- The *yyy* (`01220157RE`)
- The mode (`wc`)
- The *zzz* (`f12-1`)

  - The *zzz* prefix (`f`)
- The extension (`.tif`)

(I had to make up some words. The OP really failed at providing necessary details!)

The *xxx* and the *yyy* could be considered a single part, but I'm going with two because it allows me to use `split /_/`.

The *zzz* could be subdivided further, but it turns out that it isn't needed.

---

Now, the order. I'm guessing the following is the order we want:

1. By *xxx*, using a case-sensitive string compare.
2. By *yyy*, using a case-sensitive string compare.
3. By *zzz* prefix, `f` → others. (???)
4. By *zzz*, using a "natural" string compare.
5. By mode, `gs` → `wc` → `pc`. (???)
6. By the file name, using a case-sensitive string compare. (Probably not needed. Handles multiple file names with different extensions for the same *www*. I like having sorts that provide only one possible orderings, if only to ease testing.)

Each line after the first handles ties from the preceding line.

Note that this places `PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f10.tif` *before* `PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f10.tif`, in conflict with the stated desired output.

Note that this places `PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f12-11.tif` *before* `PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-11.tif`, in conflict with the stated desired output.

(Because of these conflicts, I might guess that the mode shouldn't be part of the sort order, except it's the one thing the OP indicated was part of the sort order. This suggests that what little information the OP did provide, the desired output, is not correct!)

---

Finally, now that we have our sort order defined, it's easy to implement.

```perl
use experimental qw( regex_sets );

use Sort::Key::Natural qw( );

use Sort::Key::Maker www_sort => \&www_key, qw( str str int nat int str );

my @ordered_modes = qw( gs wc pc );

my %mode_ranks = map { $ordered_modes[ $_ ] => $_ } 0 .. $#ordered_modes;

sub www_key {
   my ( $name, $ext ) = /^(.*)((?:\.[^.*])?)\z/s;
   my ( $xxx, $yyy, $mode, $zzz ) = split /_/, $name;
   my ( $zzz_pre ) = $zzz =~ /^((?[ \w - \d ])*)/;

   my $zzz_rank = $zzz_pre eq "f" ? 0 : 1;
   my $mode_rank = $mode_ranks{ $mode };

   return $xxx, $yyy, $zzz_rank, $zzz, $mode_rank, $_;
}
```

Usage:

```perl
my @unsorted = www_sort @unsorted;
```

`use experimental qw( regex_sets );` is safe since the experimental feature was accepted without change in 5.36, at which point `use experimental qw( regex_sets );` is no longer needed though harmless. You could also use `/^([^\W\d]*)/` instead of `/^((?[ \w - \d ])*)/`.

Comment: Champ really you awesome.+100

Comment: I have one doubt why I am getting this message might be warning _The regex_sets feature is experimental in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^((?[ <-- HERE  \w - \d ])*)/ at a.pl line 15_

Comment: Use `use experimental qw( regex_sets );`. It's safe since the experimental feature was accepted without change in 5.36, at which point `use experimental qw( regex_sets );` is no longer needed though harmless. You could also use `/^([^\W\d]*)/` instead of `/^((?[ \w - \d ])*)/`.

Comment: Hi Champ, I have integrated the above code in my primary script and the tool shows some message "Variable "_%mode_ranks" will not stay shared at,,,,_". Could you please advice on this one.

Comment: Just for reference: https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/02/perl-v5-18-adds-character-class-set-operations/

Comment: @ssr102, You appear to be using `sub f { my %mode_ranks; sub www_key { %mode_ranks } }` Nested name subs don't make sense in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

I'm about to do the same thing that @ikegami has already done, but without the fancy module. There's no problem with using that module, so this is just an alternate answer. When things get complex enough, and this is plenty complex, this straight-perl approach gets a bit unwieldy.

The same comments from @ikegami apply here. There are some things that we'd like to know about the problem.

I'm going to build up to a Schwartzian transform, which is a common way to sort items are you have to look at parts of the input rather than the whole thing. You don't want to break up the string more than once, and the Schwartzian Transform is a type of "cached key" sort.

Plenty of other places explain this technique, but here's the short summary. We have a list pipeline, where the rightmost (or bottom-most) list operations feed into the leftmost (or top-most). In the bottom `map` we create an array ref that has the original item, `$_`, as the first element, and the broken-up version as the second. We'll sort that with a subroutine that understands this, and then, in the top `map`, extract the original string again:

```
my @sorted =
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort by_mode
    map { [ $_, break_up_filename($_) }
    @files;
```

Note that we are trading memory for speed here. If you don't like that trade-off for whatever reason, you can still use what I show, but the parts are put together a bit differently.

First, we need a way to break the string into its component parts. Like @ikegami, I have to make up some names for these things. One approach is to bite of chunks and then post-process chunks, like he did, but I'll go for it in one regex that uses named captures then saves the result. The particular code in this subroutine does not matter; break up the string any way that you like:

```
sub break_up_filename {
    m/ \A
        (?<prefix>[A-Z]+)     _
        (?<base>[0-9]+[A-Z]+) _
        (?<mode>pc|wc|gs)     _
        (?<thing>f|bio) (?<thing_no>[0-9]+)
        (?: - (?<dash_n> \d+ ) )?
        (?: \. (?<ext>[a-z]+) )?
        \z
    /x;

    my %hash = %+;
    $hash{dash_n} //= -Inf;
    \%hash;
    }
```

Since not everything has the `-\d+` component, that part of the pattern is optional and I handle that by setting it's value to `-Inf` so I don't later get "Uninitialized" warnings later. Yep, that's a "number" that should sort before all other numbers.

Now that we have a hash that we can sort by its value. This is a more complex version of [How do I sort a hash (optionally by value instead of key)?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-(optionally-by-value-instead-of-key)?) from perlfaq4:

```
sub by_mode {
    state $thing_weight = {
        map { state $n = 0; $_, ++$n } qw(f bio)
        };
    state $mode_weight = {
        map { state $n = 0; $_, ++$n } qw(pc wc gs)
        };
    my( $ah, $bh ) = map { $_->[1] } ($a, $b);

    $thing_weight->{$ah->{thing}} <=> $thing_weight->{$bh->{thing}}
        ||
    $ah->{thing_no} <=> $bh->{thing_no}
        ||
    $ah->{dash_n} <=> $bh->{dash_n}  # might be -Inf
        ||
    $mode_weight->{$ah->{type}} <=> $mode_weight->{$bh->{type}}
        ||
    $ah->{prefix} cmp $bh->{prefix}
        ||
    $ah->{base} cmp $bh->{base}
        ||
    $ah->{ext} cmp $bh->{ext}
    }
```

We need to sort `f` and `bio` in that order, and I guess `pc`, `wc`, and `gs` in that order. I assign some weights to that. This is the `%mode_ranks` from @ikegami, just done differently. I do the same thing for both, where @ikegami's `$zzz_rank` uses a separate method. He could just as well use a `%thing_ranks` too. Not a big deal.

But you have a problem here. In your output, sometimes the `wc` comes before the `pc`, and other times it doesn't. I suspect that it's an oversight in the question, but if there are additional rules you just build them into the `sort` rules:

```
# from the question
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f10.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f10.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f11.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f12-1.tif
```

After we have the weights figured out, we string together some comparisons. If the two items to compare are not the same, we know their order and stop. If they are the same, we fall through the logical comparator `||` to the next comparison. We order those things so the most important comparisons are first. If the items are nubmers, we use `<=>` and if they are strings (everything not a number), we use `cmp`.

Now we put it all together:

```
#!/Users/brian/bin/perl
use v5.14;
use Mojo::Util qw(dumper);

chomp( my @files = <DATA> );

my @sorted =
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort by_mode
    map { [ $_, break_up_filename($_) ] }
    @files;

sub break_up_filename {
    $_[0] =~ m/ \A
        (?<prefix>[A-Z]+)     _
        (?<base>[0-9]+[A-Z]+) _
        (?<mode>pc|wc|gs)     _
        (?<thing>f|bio) (?<thing_no>[0-9]+)
        (?: - (?<dash_n> \d+ ) )?
        (?: \. (?<ext>[a-z]+) )?
        \z
    /x;

    my %hash = %+;
    $hash{dash_n} //= -Inf;
    \%hash;
    }

sub by_mode {
    state $thing_weight = {
        map { state $n = 0; $_, ++$n } qw(f bio)
        };
    state $mode_weight = {
        map { state $n = 0; $_, ++$n } qw(pc wc gs)
        };
    my( $ah, $bh ) = map { $_->[1] } ($a, $b);

    # sort the f and bio
    $thing_weight->{$ah->{thing}} <=> $thing_weight->{$bh->{thing}}
        ||
    $ah->{thing_no} <=> $bh->{thing_no}
        ||
    $ah->{dash_n} <=> $bh->{dash_n}
        ||
    $mode_weight->{$ah->{type}} <=> $mode_weight->{$bh->{type}}
        ||
    $ah->{prefix} cmp $bh->{prefix}
        ||
    $ah->{base} cmp $bh->{base}
    }

say join "\n", @sorted;

__DATA__
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio4.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio4.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f4.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f4.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f5.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f5.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f6.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f7.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f8.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f9.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f9.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f10.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f10.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f11.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f12-11.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f12-1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f12-2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-11.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-2.tif
```

And here's the output, which I think matches what you want mostly except for the problem I mentioned earlier:

```
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f4.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f4.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f5.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f5.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f6.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f7.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f8.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f9.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f9.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f10.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f10.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f11.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f12-1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_f12-2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_gs_f12-11.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_f12-11.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio1.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio2.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio3.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_pc_bio4.tif
PDIS_01220157RE_wc_bio4.tif
```

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating why Sort::Key is so awesome! :)

Comment: Its amazing champ. Really I need better understand the theory and coding. +100